# TabBarControllerの画面遷移について

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

`TabBarController`から他の画面に画面遷移すると、画面遷移後の`ViewController`に`TabBar`が表示されません。
そしてその`ViewController`から元の`TabBarController`のタブページに戻った時も、画面下に`TabBar`が表示されていません。
`TabBarController` → `ViewController` で`ViewController`に`TabBar`が表示されないのは今回いいとして、
`ViewController` → `TabBarController` で`TabBarController`のタブページに戻った時に`TabBar`が表示されるようにするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ナビゲーション図]
Storyboard上に上図のような構成を作り、赤矢印のようなSegueを張りました。
タブ(2)の`ViewController`から、(2)の`ViewController`に遷移すると、タブバーは消えます。しかし、(2)の`ViewController`からタブ(2)の`ViewController`にバックすると、タブバーが表示されます。あなたの構成は、こうなっていないということですね？その差異が、問題の原因を探るカギになると思います。

なお、タブ(2)の`ViewController`から、(2)の`ViewController`に遷移するとき、タブバーが消えないようにするには、タブ(2)の`ViewController`を、`UINavigationController`に置き換えることになると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。図で解説してくださり、とてもわかりやすかったです。(2)のViewControllerからタブ(2)のViewControllerに戻るときに「dismissViewControllerAnimated」を使うことでTabBarが表示されたViewControllerに戻ることができました。誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: `dismiss〜`は、モーダルビューから戻るときのメソッドであって、`NavigationController`を使った画面遷移とは異なるんですけど……ちなみに`popViewControllerAnimated()`を使います。モーダルと非モーダルを意識して区別していないと、今後もトラブルが絶えませんよ。老婆心まで。

Comment: はい、意識してモーダルと非モーダルを区別したいと思います。ありがとうございます。